# How to change the Inter-Site Topology generator

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I am planning on replacing a server in the next few weeks, and I was checking through our Active Directory Sites and Services and I noticed the server I am replacing is listed as the "Inter-Site Topology Generator". If I replace the server without changing this, what will happen?

Is it possible to change this entry to our current Domain naming operations master?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it happens automatically when the other servers notice it's missing. look towards the bottom of http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961781.aspx

> At 30-minute intervals, the current intersite topology generator notifies every other domain controller in the site of its existence by writing the attribute interSiteTopologyGenerator on the NTDS Settings object under its domain controller object in the configuration directory partition.
>
> As the interSiteTopologyGenerator attribute gets propagated to other domain controllers by Active Directory replication, the KCC on each of these computers monitors this attribute to verify that it has been written. **If a period of 60 minutes elapses without a modification, a new intersite topology generator takes over.**